# How to link multiple wasm files together in emscripten? (Not just C)

Tags: javascript, c, emscripten, webassembly

I am trying to link a .c file and a .wat file together using emscripten, so that I can call native webassembly functions from c.  I've tried several things, but none seem to work.  For instance if I try something like this:

watfile.wat

```
(module
  (func $addwat (param $p1 i32) (param $p2 i32) (result i32)
    local.get $p1     
    local.get $p2 
    i32.add 
  )
  (export "addwat" (func $addwat))
)
```

cfile.c

```
#include <emscripten.h>

int addwat( int a, int b );
int add2( int a, int b )
{
    return a+b;
}
int add2cwat( int a, int b )
{
    return addwat( a, b );
}
```

```
wat2wasm -r watfile.wat
emcc -o cfile.wasm cfile.c watfile.wasm -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["_add2","_add2cwat"]' -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall","cwrap"]' -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0 -s ASYNCIFY=1 -s EXPORT_ALL=1 -s SIDE_MODULE=1
emcc -o c-test.wasm cfile.wasm watfile.wasm  -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["_add2wat","_add2","_add2cwat"]' -s ASYNCIFY=1 -s EXPORT_ALL=1 --no-entry -s STANDALONE_WASM=1
emcc: error: undefined exported function: "_add2" [-Wundefined] [-Werror]
```

I can force everything to link, but examining the linked output, the symbols get lost. What is the proper way to link to gether multiple wasm files?  Or better yet - how it is possible to link to a wasm file from an emscripten'd C file?

EDIT:
Just as a note, you cannot seem to use wasm-ld to link emscripten outputted WASM together without sacrificing everything emscripten buys you.  I.e. it requires relocatable files `-s RELOCATABLE=1`, but you can only do that if you are just compiling a side module  `-s SIDE_MODULE=1` it seems, which means you lose `_start`

Comment: Charles, experiencing same issue - did you able to solve this connection c with webasm?

Comment: Sadly, no.  It seems they *really* want people to link at runtime, which is very annoying.